# bcrypt make: execvp: g++ : not a directory

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I am trying to install bcrypt using npm on redHat, I have it working on my Windows dev environment but it fails when I try to port it to the Unix test.

I am running npm intall bcrypt and recieving the following output:

```
$ ../../nodejs/bin/npm install bcrypt
npm WARN package.json party@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json party@0.0.0 No README data
-
> bcrypt@0.8.0 install /app/party/site/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/app/party/site/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
make: execvp: g++: Not a directory
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/app/party/site/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/app/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.18-371.el5
gyp ERR! command "node" "/app/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /app/party/site/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.31
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.18-371.el5
npm ERR! command "/app/nodejs/bin/node" "/app/nodejs/bin/npm" "install" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! cwd /app/party/site
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.23
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /app/party/site/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have been Googling for hours, but cannot work out why this is failing - please help!

Comment: Did you install all of the requirements needed to compile addons (e.g. gcc, g++, python 2.x, etc.)?

Comment: I have Python 2.7 installed, I have also run npm install node-gyp and npm install gcc.  I thought that g++ was included in gcc?

Comment: You install gcc and g++ via your distribution's package manager, not npm.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks, I have got this working, the version of GCC I was running did not include g++, unfortunately I do not have root on this box so had to install easybuild and then use that to install a new version of GCC, then include that version in the PATH, after that the npm install bcrypt worked perfectly.